# Websocket output received by browser, complains about "Invalid UTF-8 sequence in header value "

Tags: javascript, http-headers, websocket, go

When I load the page in my browser, the page gets served correctly. When the javascript executes, Chrome's console output says:

```
Invalid UTF-8 sequence in header value
```

I have searched for that string, and am unable to find any mention of it for golang.

How do I go about telling golang not to write unicode characters to web sockets?

I assume that this is the cause of the problem, as the "Network" tab only reveals an empty request and response for this.

---

CCSSE:

main.go:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "log"
  "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
  //"github.com/garyburd/go-websocket/websocket"
)

const listenAddress = "localhost:9999"

func wsHandler(webSck *websocket.Conn) {
  fmt.Fprint(webSck, "Rpy")
  fmt.Println("Sent \"Rpy\" to web socket", webSck)
  //more code here
}

func main() {
  http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
  http.Handle("/ws", websocket.Handler(wsHandler))
  err := http.ListenAndServe(listenAddress, nil)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

static/main.js

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9999/ws");
socket.onopen = function() {
  socket.onmessage = function(m) {
    console.log("Received: " + m);
  };
  socket.send("Req\n");
};
```

---

EDIT:

As suggested by @Intermernet, I have set the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header. To no avail, still getting `Invalid UTF-8 sequence in header value`.

Note also that the reason I need to do `webSck.Config().Header = make(http.Header)` is that it is `nil` - confirmed by the log statement on `webSck.Config()`. Tack on to this another question - why do I have to do this; is there an intialisation step that I have missed somewhere?

```
func wsHandler(webSck *websocket.Conn) {
  webSck.Config().Header = make(http.Header)
  webSck.Config().Header.Add("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "chat")
  fmt.Printf("ws.Config()  %#v\n", webSck.Config())
  var buf []byte;
  buf = []byte("Rpy")
  _, err := webSck.Write(buf)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
  } else {
    fmt.Printf("Sent \"Rpy\" to web socket  %#v\n", webSck)
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope you are aware that `webChatHandler` will be called on a new connection and not on message events. So, "Rpy" will be sent as soon as the connection is established, and then the connection will be terminated by the server.

Comment: @ANisus indeed, I have more code in the method, which I have omitted for purposes of brevity (this is the minimum required to reproduce the issue). Will edit to make this clear.

Comment: When I tested your code (64bit Linux) I didn't get the same error, but everything worked as expected. What kind of platform, compiler and version of Chrome do you use?

Comment: @ANisus os = Windows 7 64bit, compiler = gc, browser = Chromium 22.0.1218.0 (148522)

Comment: @ANisus go version go1.1rc3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can this issue be related to recent change in code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket ?

https://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=1e65ca1b2499c473ec267ca1d6759b3dc920a599&repo=net

Comment: I think you're right. I reverted to  48:9c2295dac419 and the problem is gone

Comment: Everton thanks for pointing this out - https://codereview.appspot.com/8731044#msg10 ... I see that @JohanBilien and yourself have already raised this issue against the commit, thanks!

Comment: @bguiz it seems the issue has been fixed already: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5457

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the comment in the form of an answer, I can't comment yet...

Are you setting Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header on the websocket Config? (https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/websocket/websocket.go?repo=net#74 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-59)

That error message seems to crop up on Google many times relating to incompatibility or conflict with that header.

Something like:

```
func wsHandler(webSck *websocket.Conn) {
  webSck.Config.Header.Add("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "chat")
  fmt.Fprint(webSck, "Rpy")
  fmt.Println("Sent \"Rpy\" to web socket", webSck)
  //more code here
}
```

Also, I think it's preferred to use the Write function on the websocket (https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/websocket/websocket.go?repo=net#205) as it encapsulates/converts the written data into frames.

So more like:

```
func wsHandler(webSck *websocket.Conn) {
  webSck.Config.Header.Add("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "chat")
  _, _ = webSck.Write("Rpy")
  fmt.Println("Sent \"Rpy\" to web socket")
  //more code here
}
```

But obviously checking the error from Write!

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Remove the extraneous ", webSck" from the fmt.Println .

Comment: `fmt.Fprint` will also use `webSck.Write`, so when it comes to websocket frames that doesn't matter. But true that the possible error returned should be checked.

Comment: @Intermernet Thanks for the answer - this didn't work, I'll update my question to show the version that I have tried. websocket.Conn.config is private, and you need to use the accessor websocket.Conn.Config() to get at it. Additonally, for some reason the value of the header is by default nil, so I had to assign it a value.

Comment: No problem, I'm pretty sure the websocket spec mentions some very useful header fields, so it's strange that library initializes it as nil. Happy coding, I'll have another look once you've updated the question.

Comment: @Intermernet I found that rather strange myself. Anyways, question updated to include what I have described.